# Incorrect password. Error 9170 VeraCrypt

Tags: veracrypt

can you help me please...

I used an external SSD drive to make a container

Every day for a year everything worked properly, I entered the password for the container and veracrypt decrypted the container.

Today I had to remove an external SSD drive and connect it to my laptop.

I installed veracrypt on my laptop, selected a file on the SSD drive that should be decrypted and got an error.

```
Operation failed due to one or more of the following:
-Incorrect password.
-Incorrect Volume PIM number.
-Incorrect PRF (hash).
-Not a valid volume.

Source: MountVolume:9170
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your disk seems to be damaged.

The first step is to find out if it's the disk itself that has developed
some bad sectors. You may find that by examining the SMART data of the
disk. If on Windows, look also for related messages in the Event Viewer.
If bad sectors exist, the disk has to be backed up and replaced.

If the disk is not damaged, then it's the VeraCrypt container that is
damaged. Take first a backup image of the disk, then use the
VeraCrypt  menu *Tools > Restore Volume Header*. Finally try the
[VeraCrypt Rescue Disk](https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/VeraCrypt%20Rescue%20Disk.html)
to try and fix the damage.

If the Rescue Disk fails, I do hope that you have backups for your data.

Comment: Could be the volume is damaged, or, if someone else has access, they changed the password: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103638/veracrypt-is-it-possible-to-change-the-password-after-an-encrypted-container-ha

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had decrypted the disk. The old password did not work anymore.

However, clicking "enter" (i.e. providing an empty password) continued with the boot normally.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread because of a very similar issue. I am not sure if this could have been the solution to your case, but possibly. Also for other users who face the same could be helpful to explain my case.

I updated Veracrypt from v1.25.4 to v1.26.7. Suddenly two encrypted partitions on two separate drives were not recognized any more, I got the exact same error message as you. I had to downgrade to access these partitions again. After a short while, I figured out that these partitions were using an old PRF hashing algorithm, RIPEMD-160, which is not supported by the new version any more (see at https://veracrypt.fr/en/Hash%20Algorithms.html). So I went to 'Volumes' > 'Set Header Key Derivation Algorithm..." and I changed it to SHA-512. Following a second upgrade to v1.26.7, everything went fine. (After this conversion, you may want to update the backups of your headers, just in case...)